# Does hashing a file consider its digital signature as well?

Tags: c++, windows, hash, digital-signature, x509certificate

I have a signed (using windows signtool) executable which is hashed by SHA1 algorithm and encrypted using RSA. Now I like to verify the executable to avoid security vulnerabilities.For that I have an idea to get the hashing algorithm from the digital signature and hash the signed executable again and compare it with the decrypted Hash using the public key found in the certificate.Would both the hash be equal.since

1. Decrypted Hash from in signature : Hashed only the binary
2. Hashing : Hashed the binary with digital signature.

I also really would like to clarify that ,can we retrieve encrypted hash from digital signature.If so how ?

Comment: The Windows signature should already do exactly that: make sure that the file is from the signing author, and wasn't changed. To verify a signature, you can use the [`Verify` command of signtool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe).

Comment: After distributing the package to the client,we can't expect that he would have a signtool. The implementation should be independent from signtool

Comment: we can only use windows default tools or windows API to verify

Comment: Did you find the Windows API for this? According to [this sample program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccrypto/example-c-program--verifying-the-signature-of-a-pe-file), it should be `WinVerifyTrust`